# intel joule 570x windows compatibility

Tags: intel, iot, windows-10-iot-core, windows-iot-core-10

Is it possible to install other versions of windows aside windows IoT Core when using Intel Joule 570? I need full windows 7/8/10 functionality if possible.
Is it out of scope for Joule?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel Joule currently supports

- [Windows 10 IoT Core](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot)
- [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/)
- [Ubuntu Core](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started)
- [Ref-OS-IoT](https://github.com/01org/ref-os-iot)

But not full versions of window 7,8,10

Comment: Do you mean Windows IoT enterprise as well? or just core edition

Comment: Just Core, I have edited my answer to reflect that. Enterprise can be installed, but many drivers are missing, and some things just don't work.

Comment: Thanks. Is enterprise similar in any way to win 10 ?? GUI, app installations (exe win32) etc etc?